# How to know when HTTP-server is done sending data

Tags: java, http, browser, proxy, webserver

I'm working on a browser/proxy oriented project where I need to download webpages. After sending a custom HTTP request to a web server I start listening for a server response.

When reading the response, I check the response headers for a Content-Length:-row. If I get one of those, it's easy to determine when the server is done sending data since I always know how many bytes of data I have received.

The problem occurs when the server doesn't include the Content-Length header and also keeps the connection open for further requests. For example, the google server responds with gzipped-content, but doesn't include content length. How do I know when to stop waiting for more data and close the connection?

I have considered using a timeout value to close the connection when no data has been received for a while, but this seems like the wrong way to do it. Chrome for example, can download the same pages as me and always seem to know exactly when to close the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at IETF RfC 2616, search for chunked encoding and Content-Range.

HTTP is designed to return content of unknown length, as in:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

25
This is the data in the first chunk

1C
and this is the second one

3
con
8
sequence
0
```

[source Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)

Comment: This seems to be the correct way to solve it if this applies to compressed data also. (which I assume it does since I have seen the Transfer-Encoding: header in some of my requests that lack Content-Length). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would try to suggest you to force `Connection: close` header so you are sure that the server closes the connection after output is finished, no matter if the `Content-length` is set or not. Performance will be partially affected by this

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is something I have already tried, but alot of servers ignore this so it's not fool-proof. Also, if one takes a look at the requests that Chrome sends, one can see that it always uses connection: keep-alive but still knows when it's done. Therefore I think this is (even though it sometimes works) the wrong way to solve it.

Comment: If server ignore connection: close then you have a big trouble and need to use a very short timeout (like 2 seconds). Connection:close requires the server to close the connection. Not closing the connection is a protocol violation. Also, I may suspect that Chrome expects the </html> tag to determine "it's finished"

Comment: I don't think so, because it wouldn't make sense to read the HTML-tags of a compressed document until it's decompressed. Take a look at bew's answer. Chrome solves it by reading the chunk size.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases you can expect:
1. socket-close
2. socket-timeout

Usually the socket will be closed, it also make sense to declare an Socket Timeout.

Remember

```
 int stream.read(byte[],size);
```

returns the real size of byte[]-argument's size that has been read till socket-close or socket-timeout (or size-argument reached).

Regards.