# ServerSocket doesn't work with try-with-resources?

Tags: java, try-catch, serversocket, try-with-resources

So we're fooling around with ServerSockets in class, making a very simple HTTP server that takes a request, does nothing with it, and responds with a 200 OK followed by some HTML content.

I've been trying to figure out this problem for two days, and I haven't been able to get to grips with it, and neither has my teacher. I've come to think it is a problem with closing the server, for some odd reason. I've fixed the problem, but would just like to know why I happened in the first place.

Here are three snippets:

HttpServer.class:

```
package httpserver;

import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HttpServer implements Closeable {
    public static final int PORT = 80;
    public static final int BACKLOG = 1;
    public static final String ROOT_CATALOG = "C:/HttpServer/";

    private ServerSocket server;
    private Socket client;
    private Scanner in;
    private PrintWriter out;

    private String request;

    public HttpServer() throws IOException {
        server = new ServerSocket(PORT, BACKLOG);
    }

    public Socket accept() throws IOException {
        client = server.accept();
        in = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
        out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());

        return client;
    }

    public void recieve() {
        request = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(request);
    }

    public void respond(final String message) {
        out.print(message);
        out.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if(!server.isClosed()) {
            client = null;
            server = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Main.class solution that ***works***:

```
package httpserver;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpServer server = new HttpServer();
        Socket client;

        while(true) {
            client = server.accept();
            server.recieve();
            server.respond("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
                    + "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
                    + "\r\n"
                    + "<html><body><b>hello..</b></body></html>");
            client.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Main.class solution that ***doesn't work***:

```
package httpserver;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(HttpServer server = new HttpServer()) {
            while (true) {
                server.accept();
                server.recieve();
                server.respond("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
                        + "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
                        + "\r\n"
                        + "<html><body><b>hello..</b></body></html>");
            }
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("We have a problem: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I could imagine it has something to do with not closing the client socket after each loop iteration. But even so, it should at least go through once, before bugging up in that case. I really can't see what the problem is supposed to be.

No error messages, nothing...

Comment: @G-Man `Closeable` extends `AutoCloseable`, so it isn't.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: @ChrisCooney I tried, but i'm very unsure as to how I can debug something like this. NetBeans debugger isn't exactly the friendliest debugger in the world on some occassions.

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? Your attempt to implement HTTP in the HttpServer class is so incomplete that I am surprised that even the first Main class does anything useful. Since the only difference is that the second Main class doesn't close the network socket, I would assume that your browser is actually waiting for more data and just seems to do "nothing".

Comment: @jarnbjo What is so incomplete about it?

Comment: @Volatile: You could have found the answer in the RFCs for HTTP. Most obvious problems are that you are only reading the first line of the request and that you respond with a hard coded version "1.0", though the server must respond using the same version as in the client request.

Comment: @Volatile Come off it. *Everything* is incomplete about it. You are ignoring the resource requested; you are sending back the wrong HTTP version; you are sending back a hard-coded response; you aren't sending back a Content-Length: header; you are ignoring all the headers except the first; you are closing the connection even when the client asks you not to; ...

Comment: HTTP version isn't wrong. Sorry, but i'm not required to comply with whatever version the client wants to run in this case. As was stated in the beginning; this is a simple web server for school, where I don't want to keep the connection open (1.1). And frankly, the headers aren't useful for me, and neither are they obligatory (except for your point on content-length, which was fixed with closing the client socket anyway). I'm not building this for fortune 500 companies, so please chill out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not specify any [Content-length](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html#BodyLength) when sending the HTTP, so the browser does not know when to stop reading for more data. See [How to know when HTTP-server is done sending data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412945/how-to-know-when-http-server-is-done-sending-data) for more info.

In the working example you closed the client socket, which tells the browser there is no more data - for your ambitions this might be enough if you don't want the browser to respond.